# Requesting reopening of question

Tags: support, reopen

Please reopen the question.

[Physics-based derivation of the formula for entropy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44647/physics-based-derivation-of-the-formula-for-entropy)

I have complied with David Z request indicated in the comments.

Comment: For reference's sake, [here is the review history](http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/6219) showing that only two people reviewed it after the closing back in Nov 2012; the sole reopen vote would have expired after ~1 week.

Comment: To be frank, David was very honestly trying to help you improve your question.

Comment: Perhaps, Is it good enough now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After gaining the [necessary 5 votes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/44647/revisions), the question is now reopened.

Note also that you can force a closed question into the automatic review queues by making edits to the question. Making a separate Meta post is not a necessity (though, in this case, it is possible that the age of the question might have prevented that?).

Comment: Side note -- it seems odd that the author of a question can vote to reopen a question. Presumably the OP would *always* want their question open, otherwise he/she wouldn't have posted it to begin with.